# Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission in WPF XBAP

Tags: wpf, xbap

I'm simply running a small piece of code in a button click event of a WPF application.

The code simply connects to the database to retrieve images and display on the form.

But,I get this Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission Exception..

Please help me with this....
Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard that this is not possible directly from a Silverlight app (which I guess also applies to WPF XBAP) since its a security issue.

The alternate way is to have a WCF service and retrieve data through the  WCF service.